# Django throws Operational Error with substituted Auth Model

Tags: python, django, authentication

apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question. To the best of my searches, I was not able to find this question.

Using Django 2.0, I substituted the built-in django.contrib.auth with my own Users model, extending it with AbstractUser. The Users model is dependent on an existing table in MySQL, which is configured to work with Django. Django does not detect any issues when performing a check; however, I receive the following error:

```
OperationalError at / (1054, "Unknown column 'users.last_login' in 'field list'")
```

I added the column into the table thinking it would be a useful field to have, but was apprehensive because I figured I'd get another error for another missing field. Lo and behold:

```
OperationalError at / (1054, "Unknown column 'users.is_superuser' in 'field list'")
```

The point of substituting the user model is so I can ditch unimportant fields, such as "username". Do I just need to add each column to the table until I get all the auth fields in the table, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

TL;DR: How do I create a custom authentication method for Django using an existing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying, you are getting these errors, because your table doesn't have the columns for fields defined in `AbstractUser` model. The easiest solution is to just add all the missing fields to your table.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid that, you can have your user model subclass `AbstractBaseUser` instead. This abstract model has only fields for `password` and `last_login`. Note, that this approach is going to be a bit more work. This seems to be a good guide on how to do it:

[https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser)

Comment: AbstractBaseUser was the way to go. A bit of a pain to set up a new table for, but overall worth it. Thank you very much for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
"I have fixed this problem after a lot of tries. Just pass AbstractBaseUser in the class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser) and don't include PermissionsMixin in the parameters and for the extra column which are not matching include last_login = None and the CustomUser model will run as expected. 
Adding the code for reference. "


from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
import re
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.mail import send_mail
# from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, loginId, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not loginId:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        # email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(loginId=loginId, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, loginId, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(loginId, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, loginId, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(loginId, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    userId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    loginId = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    userType = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=[
            ('0', 'walmart'),
            ('1', 'partner'),
            ('2', 'forecaster'),
            ('3', 'supervisor'),
        ],
        default='0'
    )
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    emailId = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    lobId = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    channelId = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    createdDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lastLoginDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    lastLoginIp = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=[
            ('0', 'inactive'),
            ('1', 'active'),
            ('2', 'deleted'),
        ]
    )
    last_login = None
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'loginId'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'rpt_admin'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.loginId)  

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.userType)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).